# Is it possible to wrap some code in c# instead of using comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, comments

I am new to programming in c# and I have started to develop a project of around 500 lines. I have many functions and variables declared and iam using comments near the code to make it easy to identify code blocks like:

```
//code for login button
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

But this is little difficult for me. Is there any other way in visual studio 2008 that can make my code easy to identify and read? Please help... Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `#region` for this.

`#region` lets you specify a block of code that you can expand or collapse. Its a good option when you want to wrap up your code and give it some name.

```
#region My wrapped code  
public class Sample   
{  
  static void Main()   
  {  
  }  
}  
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use outlining feature..
Select the code you want to hide, right click on it and choose "Outlining" - "Hide selection" (Ctrl + M, Ctrl + H). The same result as with regions, but without them.

Answer (score -3):

just type `///` ;-)

you can use `/* bla bla bla */` too, this is a classic multi-line-comment

Comment: `///` is for xml comments, method documentation,  not for wrapping code

Comment: `///` gives you code-insight etc... see MSDN for additional information about that, here you can specify a lot of details.

Comment: @Habib where is written, that he want's to WRAP code? he wants to make it more clear to read and manage...